# PropTypes : PropTypes.array VS PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any)

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes

Consider this :

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

[...]

Component.propTypes = {
  someProp: PropTypes.array,
}
```

and :

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

[...]

Component.propTypes = {
  someProp: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any),
}
```

The first will make `eslint` trigger error in editor :

`Prop type 'array' is forbidden   eslint(react/forbid-prop-types)`

However, they both will trigger the same error if condition is not respected, and according to the documentation, it should behave the exact same way.

**Is there any difference between those two validations ?**

(And can I ignore this error ?)

Comment: The intent behind the [eslint rule](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/forbid-prop-types.md) is to say that `PropTypes.array` is a very generic type. It could be an array of literally anything. If your component doesn't care what's in the array, meaning that it works even if the array has mixed numbers, strings, objects or React elements or even functions, you can just disable the warning for that line. If you only deal with an array of specific types, e.g. an array of strings or an array of objects with a specific shape, use `arrayOf` with the right type.

Comment: This is an error thrown by eslint. Since you or your team are the ones who specify what linter rules to use you should absolutely not ignore this error. If this is a rule your or your team don't like and don't want to follow then you can just agree to disable it. Also there's no practical difference between `PropTypes.array` and `PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any)` if you decide you don't like one you should also not like the other equally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the difference is

`PropTypes.array` scans for

- array of objects `[{name:'ABC'},{name:'XYZ'}]`
- array of strings `['Lorem','Ipsum']`
- array of integers `[2,4,66,4]`
- array of nested arrays `[['d'],[[{name:'a'},{name:'b'}]]]`
- array of functions `[foo,bar]`

and much more

**Whereas for `PropTypes.arrayOf` would accept parameters that which type of values would be inside array. Like more strict rule**

`PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number)` scans for only

- array of integers `[2,4,66,4]` because you mentioned `PropTypes.number`

and would show warning/error if there was another data type

Same goes for every primitive(integers, strings) and non-primitive types(objects,functions,arrays)

Like
`PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string)` scans for

- array of strings `['Lorem','Ipsum']`

Reference - https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes

Comment: So as I understand this, if I provide `PropTypes.any` as argument to `PropType.arrayOf()`, if will have the same behaviour as `PropTypes.array`

Comment: Your link is deprecated, [here is the newer one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)